# which is better href="#" or href="javascript:void();"

Tags: javascript, html, web

which is better `href="#"` or `href="javascript:void();"` in terms of all aspects

like user experience, speed etc

is it necessary to put a 0 inside void when using `href="javascript:void();"` .like this `href="javascript:void(0);"`

Comment: Better is not to use `anchor` elements if you don't need `links` :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a link - don't use the `<a>` element. You can use any other element (`div`/`span`) and attach a click event to it:

```
EL.addEventListener('click', function() { ... })
```

The `EL` in the above example can by `document.getElementById('#div-id')` for example or any other `DOM` element.

Comment: An element where you click on it and something happens? `<button>`.